# Data Flow Testing Tool/Software

Tags: open-source, software-testing, dataflow

I am looking for data flow testing tool/software. I have searched many times on the internet. But, I couldn't find any of them to fulfill my requirements. For example, [Pestt](http://pestt.github.io/), this tool for control flow testing. Tool/software I'm looking for is described as below:

1. It's free or open source,
2. It have documentation and tutorial,
3. Desktop or web based application, and
4. Programming language for testing doesn't matter.
5. I desire if the tool can generate data flow graph from given source code program, test requirements, test path, and coverage result in statistic.

If anyone know the tool/software, but it doesn't meet my description. Feel free to give a suggestion. I am always welcome your respond. Thanks.

Summary of **data flow testing** can be found [here](http://www.khannur.com/stb6.2.htm).

Comment: I think you need to define "data flow testing" more carefully.

Comment: @Ira Baxter would you like to give explanation about that case?

Comment: @Ira Baxter, I am so sorry, can you give me an example to define "data flow testing"? I am little bit confused here.

Comment: I have edited my question, adding the term of data flow testing with given link above.

Comment: You might find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30535347/120163

Comment: What did you finally do?

Comment: Well, actually, I didn't find any tool. So, I gave up.

Comment: It is clear that there's been lots of research involving this (This reference is pretty nice: http://ix.cs.uoregon.edu/~michal/book/slides/pdf/PezzeYoung-Ch13-DFTest.pdf  ) over quite a long time.  I did a Google search and could not find a tool that did this anywhere.   It appears your only alternative is a tool built custom.  What was the application that motivated the need for this?

Comment: Thank you so much for help @Ira Baxter. The motivation why I need this at that time I had a task to explain data flow testing either manually with text/examples or automatically with tools.

Comment: I had an exchange with Michal Young (the source of the slides linked).  He indicated that DF testing "never got much traction in practice ... partly because data flow [in real programs] with pointers and aliases and arrays is ... hard ...  and program analysis frameworks [were/are] basically nonexistent. ...I (Michal) can't think of a single available tool that provides it".  And he's the expert.

Comment: I'm not worried;  I have my own interests here :-}